# Flash Movie Not Loaded in IE6

Tags: internet-explorer, flash

I have a .swf file that I try to browse to and it loads fine in Firefox, but in IE6 it doesn't load.  When right-clicking it says "movie not loaded".

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you tell us more about your flash version? security limitations differ from one version to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was the application uses SSL with client authentication and there is a strange issue where when loading the application in IE it wasn't filling out a certain header in the HTTP request, so I had to use a custom servlet filter which inserted the header.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the OBJECT element has a child PARAMETER elememt named movie and an attribute called data that both point to your SWF file.

Comment: Do you mean,

<param name="movie" value="myfile.swf" />

Comment: Yes and the object needs the data attribute so you have something a bit like;
    <object data="myfile.swf">
      <parameter name="movie" value="myfile.swf"/>
    </object>

Answer (score 2):

Can you post the html you're using to embed the move in the page?

I have to admit, though, that I find all the nuances of embedding flash to be a headache. I can never remember them all, so I rely on this project to handle all the browser variations for me: http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/.  You might find that using swfobject helps make the problem "just go away" :-)  Their docs also have some 'non-javascript' fallbacks if you need that.

Answer (score 0):

A really *really* easy way to publish flash to HTML is simply hitting **F12** key in Flash. This will publish the SWF on a blank HTML page. This no-brainer technique will work seamlessly on all browsers.

Otherwise, for cleaner implementation, i recommend swfObject (see Jarret Hardie's link above).

Answer (score 0):

Whenever u publish swf file, that time u need to change flash player to 5.0,
means swf publish in older version.

Answer (score 0):

Lookup swf object

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Just copy and paste the code below inside your tag (tested in Firefox, IE6, IE7, IE8):

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"       codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=5,0,0,0" width="750" height="500">
   <param name=movie value="../FolderName/FlashFile.swf">
   <param name=quality value=high>
   <embed src="../FolderName/FlashFile.swf" quality=high pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="750" height="500"></embed> 
</object>
```